# Oracle Database Docker

Tags: database, oracle, docker

I'm new in oracle and I have a docker image of oracle database, I'm able to run it and here is the output:

```
[root@ip-10-0-20-67 ~]# docker logs -f hungry_keller
ls: cannot access /u01/app/oracle/oradata: No such file or directory
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Starting tnslsnr
Copying database files
1% complete
3% complete
11% complete
18% complete
37% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
40% complete
45% complete
50% complete
55% complete
56% complete
60% complete
62% complete
Completing Database Creation
66% complete
70% complete
73% complete
85% complete
96% complete
100% complete
Look at the log file "/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/xe/xe.log" for further details.
Configuring Apex console
Database initialized. Please visit http://#containeer:8080/em http://#containeer:8080/apex for extra configuration if needed
Starting web management console

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Starting import from '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d':
found file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d//docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
[IMPORT] /entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

Import finished

Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)
```

But I don't know how to access it, username and password is prompted if I try and access it using `localhost:8080` and I don't know the credentials. 
I actually want to create a database just like mysql command line or with any GUI interface and connect it through eclipse.

*Here is the link of the docker image I used:*

https://hub.docker.com/r/konnecteam/oracle12c-database/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you check the other images of [konnecteam](https://hub.docker.com/u/konnecteam/), for instance [docker-oracle-12c](https://hub.docker.com/r/konnecteam/docker-oracle-12c/), you can find complete installation and management instructions, along with their default username/password for Oracle databases, and its always the same:

> Connect database with following setting:
>
> ```
> hostname: localhost
> port: 1521
> sid: xe
> service name: xe.oracle.docker
> username: system
> password: oracle
> ```

AND

> Connect to Oracle Application Express web management console with
>   following settings:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/apex
> workspace: INTERNAL
> user: ADMIN
> password: 0Racle$
> ```

AND

> Connect to Oracle Enterprise Management console with following
>   settings:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/em
> user: sys
> password: oracle
> connect as sysdba: true
> ```

There's no instructions for the image you are using, and I admit that it is confusing. They will probably update this in the future.

Comment: @ Thomas G there u go

Comment: I am having the same issue but I could not connect with the information you shared :( Tried my luck on Stack overflow on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75706071/oracle-database-from-official-docker-files-do-not-connect-on-macbook

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to use the official Docker images from Oracle found here:
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

You will be required to download the installer binaries from [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/) (Oracle Technology Network) or the [Oracle Software Delivery Cloud](https://edelivery.oracle.com). You will need to agree the terms of use and ensure that you have/use the appropriate licenses. There are instructions on how you can configure and use your choice of password as well.

The non-XE containers will have Oracle Enterprise Manager Express configured. Using EM Express, you should be able to create users and tablespaces if required. Alternatively, you can use [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html) to manage the database.

Comment: i think we just want some simple documentation on the docker page to start. otherwise, it's a major rabbit hole and just a bad joke imo

Comment: The official image need to download the binary file :/